# mysql year lower than 1900

Tags: mysql, macos, windows-7

i created a table "composers" VALUES (name VARCHAR(30), birth YEAR(4), death YEAR(4), city VARCHAR(30), country VARCHAR(30)). then i INSERT INTO composers VALUES ('BACH Johann Sebastian',1685,1750,'Eisenach','Germany');. it returns 2 errors. the years are not between 1901 and 2155.

is there any way of changing this default so i can have an actual year for those columns? cant seem to find anything on the web.

i resorted to just use INTEGER(4) for those columns but would like to use YEAR(4) if it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems quite clear that this is the only way this type works in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html).

The `YEAR(4)` type only uses 1 byte, and is limited to a range of 256 years. If your use case falls completely within a different 256 year space, you could certainly store them off by a certain amount, and adjust the yourself before writing and after reading, say by -300.

Alternatively, use a `SMALLINT` or `UNSIGNED SMALLINT` instead of a full `INT` to use 2 bytes. Not quite the 1 byte that a 'YEAR(4)' uses, but less than the 4 bytes for an `INT`

Comment: 1 byte of data can store at most value of 255 not 256. 11111111 = 255. MySQL `year` type can store year in range 1901-2155.

Comment: @instead 1 byte of date can store 256 different values, 0 through 255. It turns out that MySQL uses 255 of those values for the years 1901 to 2155, and one more for invalid (0000).

Answer (score 1):

The [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) datatype only supports that range. If you want to use other values, use a standard `INT`.

The only advantage to using the `YEAR` type is semi-automatic conversion from 2-digit years to 4-digit equivalents, but that utility is dubious at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use integer to store years as number (what you already did), or switch to more sensible database like PostgreSQL, which does not have any problems with storing dates millions of years into the past or into the future.

Comment: This is of course slight exaggeration :-). Real range is from 4713 BC to 5874897 AD. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to use Int for this case 
According to this 
http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file

The range of year type is from 1900 - 2155, can't be changed :)